# Should I reset running averages of Ray actor in reset_config when reuse_actors=True?

Tags: ray

Looking at the [pbt_example](https://github.com/ray-project/ray/blob/60d4d5e1aaa9fde3cf541ee335e284d05e75679c/python/ray/tune/examples/pbt_example.py), I see that the actor's accumulated `accuracy` is not reset to zero in `reset_config`, only the new hyperparameters are set (including changing `lr` in particular). While implementing my own actor, which as state has a running average of the current metric that should be minimized by the hyperparameter sweep, I was wondering if I should reset this running average to zero or not in `reset_config`? The implications of either resetting this state or not are not clear from the documentation and from browsing the source files of `ray.tune`.

Would appreciate some clarification on `reuse_actors` and `reset_config`, in particular. The documentation is unfortunately a bit vague in this respect. Otherwise great library and easy to get started!

Comment: Thanks a lot for making this issue!  ``reuse_actors`` is useful when ``_setup`` takes a long period of time to run.  By setting it to True, there is a possibility of not calling ``_setup`` in a future trial because the trial actor/process is being reused.  This is where ``reset_config`` comes in - it allows you to specify exactly what should happen when Tune reuses an actor. You should reset the running average to 0 in this case.

Does that help answer your question? More than happy to improve docs here!

Comment: Thanks, @richliaw, for this clear answer! I would accept if it was submitted as answer rather than comment :-)

Comment: One addition, if `reset_config` serves the same purpose as `_setup`, except for some additional setup steps that may be needed during first object initialization (construction), wouldn't it makes sense for the `Trainable` base class to have a `_setup` and `_set_config` type of functions, where `__init__` calls first `_setup` and then `_set_config`? That way the base class would already encourage no code duplication for common setup steps regardless if actor is being initialized the first time or for consecutive trials.